# How to fix 'Input/output error' while extracting zipfile?

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I am working with a 150GB+ zipfile of dicom images.
I am trying to extract some of these by their filenames.

I am working on google collab python 3 interpreter and use zipfile module along with `ZipFile.extractall()` method on a list of filenames of length 500 (ex : ['stage_1_train_images/ID_53ff71bc4.dcm', 'stage_1_train_images/ID_001bb2c00.dcm',etc...]) :
.

Here's my code :

```
from zipfile import ZipFile 

with ZipFile(src, 'r') as zipObj:
     zipObj.extractall(members = ids, path = '/content/drive/My Drive/RSNA IH DETECTION CHALLENGE/DICOM') #ids is my file list
```

I got an error message :

```
"OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error", related to a message in read(self, n) :    "727     "Close the writing handle before trying to read.")"
```

I tried to close the file and re-open it, tried to extract with the .extract() method several times and always got the same err message.

I first attempted to use fuse zip along with `shutil.copyfile()` but it failed to...

Do you know what's causing this error message and a possible way to fix it?

Comment: are you sure `ids` doesn't contain a zip file of the same name as the src zip file?

Comment: unfortunately not : my src zip file is called 'rsna-intracranial-hemorrhage-detection.zip', my ids are all of the form 'stage_1_train_images/ID_\w{9}.dcm'

Comment: have you tried to unzip it using a standard unzip command? maybe the file is corrupt.

Comment: since I m limited in storage capabilities to 350GB, when I tried a standard unzip command (by that I suppose you mean ZipFile.extractall() method I figure), it crashed my environment ...

Comment: you could try to unzip only some files by using extra args to unzip. Also test with smaller files. And I meant to use a non-python `unzip` executable

Comment: I succeed in fixing this problem ! You were right JF Fabre when you said the file might be corrupted. Indeed, I re-download the .zip file from Kaggle, instead of my google Drive environment and fuse zip works as well as ZipFil method ! Maybe G Drive has trouble with storing huge files ? 
Thank's for your help !

Comment: don't you want to share the fix with a self-answer?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with re-downloading the original file.
My version, stored on Google Drive was probably corrupted. 
Now fuse-zip works as well as ZipFile methods !